# HLA RTI and Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, high-level-architecture

For a simulation project we would like to connect Unity3d with the HLA RTI from Portico. But the problem is we don't know whether it is possible. If yes how it is working. By the way we may use another RTI. It doesn't have to be Portico. But our game engine must be Unity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've changed the tag, since the `hla` tag refers to High Level Assembly, not High Level Architecture (simulation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It surely is possible.

You will need to create some federation in Unity.

You do have commercial rtis from Pitch and Mak, for instance.

There's a plugin from Mak that already does that.

Best regards,
Daniel